# Can the as400 timestamp (yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ssssss) be used for querying irrespective of the device time format?

Tags: db2, websphere

Date format of the machine is yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss
(yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ssssss) 1988-12-25-17.12.30.000000 this is my time format input, Can this time format be used to query logs from historic_log_info table? Irrespective of the date format set in the machine.
example query - `SELECT * FROM TABLE(HISTORY_LOG_INFO( START_TIME => '2021-02-22-09.35.16.508075'))WHERE MESSAGE_ID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: ps-no ibm as400 device to try on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description for end-time, that formating looks correct:

> start-time
> A timestamp expression that indicates the starting timestamp to use when returning history log information.
> If this parameter is omitted, the default of CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY is used.

> end-time
> A timestamp expression that indicates the ending timestamp to use when returning history log information.
> If this parameter is omitted, the default of **'9999-12-30-00.00.00.000000'** is used.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajq/rzajqudfhistoryloginfo.htm

Comment: This query  `SELECT * FROM TABLE(HISTORY_LOG_INFO( START_TIME => '2021-02-22-09.35.16.508075'))` returns the logs with the date format as "2021-03-02 17:42:43.615999" (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) which is different from the given input format. Also, the device has a date format set -> MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss which is totally different from the output I received.  Is it the correct behaviour is the response format generic to all IBM as400 device irrespective of the format specified??